# How to properly connect the Codemirror library to Angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular, codemirror

Documentation here http://codemirror.net 
And for Angular https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-codemirror
Installed
1) npm install ng2-codemirror
2) npm install codemirror
3) In app.module.ts

```
import { CodemirrorModule } from 'ng2-codemirror';
@NgModule({
  // ...
  imports:      [
    CodemirrorModule
  ],
  // ...
})
```

4) In .angular-cli.json

```
  "styles": [
    "../node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css",
    "styles.scss"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js"
  ],
```

5) Instead of textarea wrote

```
<codemirror
  *ngIf="chaptersService.currentChapter" 
  [(ngModel)]="chaptersService.currentChapter.novel"
  [config]="{lineNumbers: true}"
  autofocus
  (keyup)="markAsEdited()"
  #textareaNovel>
</codemirror>
```

Classes are applied from Codemirror, but I can not enter text.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please move the ng-if in a div above and do not use the  tag and use [autofocus]=true and remove the last #

```
 <div *ngIf="chaptersService.currentChapter">
    <codemirror 
      [(ngModel)]="chaptersService.currentChapter.novel"
      [config]="{lineNumbers: true}"
      [autofocus]=true
      (keyup)="markAsEdited()">
    </codemirror>
</div>
```